# Adding two vectors using pthreads without a global sum variable

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I am trying to calculate the sum of two vectors a and b using pthreads in C. I am given a function that computes the sum in sequential form and another which does so in parallel form. My program is working properly but computing different sums when there are multiple threads. I have used proper thread synchronization on the critical area, but still cannot see where I am going wrong. I get the correct answer on the first thread since there is only one thread doing the job and then I get wrong answers on multiple threads. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>


// type for value of vector element
typedef short value_t;
// type for vector dimension / indices
typedef long index_t;
// function type to combine two values
typedef value_t (*function_t)(const value_t x, const value_t y);
// struct to store the respective values of the vectors a,b and c
typedef struct{
    index_t start;
    index_t end;
    value_t *arr;
    value_t *brr;
    value_t *crr;
    value_t *part_sum;
    pthread_mutex_t *mutex;
}arg_struct;

// function to combine two values
value_t add(const value_t x, const value_t y) {
  return ((x+y)*(x-y)) % ((int)x+1) +27;
}


// function to initialize the vectors a,b and c
void vectorInit(index_t n, value_t a[n], value_t b[n], value_t c[n]) {

  for(index_t i=0; i<n; i++) {
    a[i] = (value_t)(2*i);
    b[i] = (value_t)(n-i);
    c[i] = 0;
  }
}


// function to count the sum of two variables sequentially
value_t vectorOperation(index_t n, value_t a[n], value_t b[n], value_t c[n], function_t f) {

  value_t sum = 0;

  for(index_t i=0; i<n; i++) {
    sum += (c[i] = f(a[i], b[i]));
  }

  return sum;
}
/* Thread function */
void* vector_sum(void* arg)
{   
    arg_struct *param = (arg_struct*)arg;
   /*
    for(index_t i= param->start; i<param->end; i++)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&param->mutex);
        *param->part_sum += vectorOperation(i,param->arr,param->brr,param->crr,add);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&param->mutex);
    }
    */
    index_t n = param->end - param->start;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&(*param->mutex));
    // Each thread uses the vectorOperation function to calculate the sum sequentially(Also the critical area)
    *param->part_sum = *param->part_sum + vectorOperation(n,param->arr,param->brr,param->crr,add);
    //*param->part_sum += vectorOperation(param->end-param->start,param->arr,param->brr,param->crr,add);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&(*param->mutex));

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}



// Sum of two vectors in parallel. 
value_t vectorOperationParallel(index_t n, value_t a[n], value_t b[n], value_t c[n], function_t f, int p) {

  value_t sum = 0;

    pthread_t threads[p];
    arg_struct thread_args[p];
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex,NULL);
    index_t div = (n+p-1)/p;

      for(int i=0; i<p; i++)
    {
        thread_args[i].start = i*div;
        thread_args[i].end = (i+1)*div;
        thread_args[i].arr = a;
        thread_args[i].brr = b;
        thread_args[i].crr = c;
          for(int j =0; j<div; j++)
          {
          thread_args[i].arr[j] = a[thread_args[i].start+j];
          thread_args[i].brr[j] = b[thread_args[i].start+j];
          thread_args[i].crr[j] = c[thread_args[i].start+j];

          }
        thread_args[i].part_sum = &sum;
        thread_args[i].mutex = &mutex;
        pthread_create(&threads[i],NULL,vector_sum, (void*)&thread_args[i]);
    }


    for(int i=0; i<p; i++)
    {
        pthread_join(threads[i],NULL);
    }
  return sum;
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  // check for correct argument count
  if (argc != 3)
    {
      printf ("usage: %s vector_size n_threads\n", argv[0]);
      exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

  // get arguments
  // vector size
  index_t n = (index_t)atol (argv[1]);
  // number of threads
  int p = atoi (argv[2]);
  // check for plausible values
  if((p < 1) || (p > 1000)) {
      printf("illegal number of threads\n");
      exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  // allocate memory
  value_t *a = malloc(n * sizeof(*a));
  value_t *b = malloc(n * sizeof(*b));
  value_t *c = malloc(n * sizeof(*c));
  if((a == NULL) || (b == NULL) || (c == NULL)) {
    printf("no more memory\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  // initialize vectors a,b,c
  vectorInit(n, a, b, c);

  // work on vectors sequentially
  value_t c1sum = vectorOperation(n, a, b, c, add);

  // work on vectors parallel for all thread counts from 1 to p
  for(int thr=1; thr<= p; thr++) {
    // do operation
    value_t c2sum = vectorOperationParallel(n, a, b, c, add, thr);

    // check result
    if(c1sum != c2sum) {
      printf("!!! error: vector results are not identical !!!\nsum1=%ld, sum2=%ld\n", (long)c1sum, (long)c2sum);
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    } 
    else
        printf("The results are equal: sum1=%ld, sum2=%ld\n",(long)c1sum, (long)c2sum);
  }

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
```

Comment: `pthread_mutex_init` in a loop is probably a bad idea.

Comment: @n.m.  That's true, I have fixed that in my code, but that doesn't seem to be where the problem is coming from.

Comment: @n.m. I think the problem I'm' having is when I'm passing the lock in the struct.

Comment: I don't see that you fixed that in the question.

Comment: also can you explain this : `index_t div = (n + p - 1) / p;`

Comment: @KamiKaze that is the size of the chunks that I'm splitting the area up into and each thread is going to take a chunk.

Comment: `typedef long index_t;` don't do that, use `size_t`

Answer (score 0):

Okay I am not sure but this seems to be what is wrong.

At first the names for the variables are horrible.

then n.m. commented:

> pthread_mutex_init in a loop is probably a bad idea

you calculate `index_t div = (elements_in_vector + num_of_threads - 1) / num_of_threads;` 
And later you use `div * num_of_threads` to distrubute the elements. This way you may try to access more elements than there are available.

example:

```
index_t div = (elements_in_vector + num_of_threads - 1) / num_of_threads;
//(13 * 5 - 1) / 5 = 3
thread_args[i].end = (i + 1) * div; // for the last i ( = 2)
//(2 + 1) * 5 = 15
```

As soon as you access `i >= 13` you get garbage values (undefined behaviour)

Then you make a copy of parts of your original array (I would assume this is slower then just passing a reference to the original).

You don't seem to use the result array `*thread_args[i].crr` at all.

You only need the mutex for the sum of all values as you have dedicated memory for every array you pass in the thread. You could even pass pointers of the original arrays to the threads without a mutex if you would not use the sum variable in all of them. Because as every addition is self contained and does not access memory of another addition, no mutex is needed.

To calculate the sum of all value you could just use the return value of the thread instead of a reference to a value you pass to every one. This way it would be much faster.

I am not sure if I found everything, but this may help you improve this a good bit.